# How to return comma delimited string from array, in React Native

Tags: arrays, react-native, dictionary, join, delimited

I have an array and I want to extract a specific column's values and return the items in a comma-delimited string. 
What is the best way to go about this?
For the below array I would like to get the values of name and return "John,Tim,Mike"
Thanks for any assistance

```
const users = [{
  "name": "John",
  "color": "blue",
},{
  "name": "Tim",
  "color": "red",
},{
  "name": "Mike",
  "color": "green",
}]
```

I would like to return the results in a comma-delimited string

```
str = "John,Tim,Mike"
```

Thanks again for any assistance.

Comment: `users.map(u => u.name).join(",");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can map to extract names, then run a join:

```js
const users = [{
  "name": "John",
  "color": "blue",
},{
  "name": "Tim",
  "color": "red",
},{
  "name": "Mike",
  "color": "green",
}];

const commaSep = users.map(item => item.name).join(', ');

console.log(commaSep);
```